# puppeteer: How can the save button be clicked after the form is filled out?

Tags: typescript, react-hooks, automated-tests, puppeteer

How can the save button be clicked after the form is filled out?

```
<div class="MuiDialogActions-root MuiDialogActions-spacing">
   <button class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiButton-root MuiButton-outlined MuiButton-outlinedPrimary" tabindex="0" type="button">
     <span class="MuiButton-label">Cancel</span>
     <span class="MuiTouchRipple-root"></span>
  </button>
  <button class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiButton-root MuiButton-contained MuiButton-containedPrimary" tabindex="0" type="submit">
     <span class="MuiButton-label">Save</span>
     <span class="MuiTouchRipple-root"></span>
   </button>
</div>
```

My suggested solution is:

```
await page.waitForSelector('.MuiButton-label')
await page.click('.MuiButtonBase-label[name=save]')
```

But it doesn work.

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not able to change the HTML then I rather would suggest doing it like:

```
await page.click('button[type=submit]')
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! 
I added something to my question. can you please give me feedback on this